# Get the next possible day and hour given the current day

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Im trying to write some logic so I can data-bind when the next occurrence will be out of a set of models based on the current date and time

sample data would be as follows. Days represents each day that is scheduled, hour is the hour it starts and enabled is self explanatory:

```
var collection = [{
    days: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    hour: 8,
    enabled: true }, {
    days: [0, 1, 4, 5, 6],
    hour: 14,
    enabled: true }, {
    days: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6],
    hour: 2,
    enabled: false }, {
    days: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6],
    hour: 14,
    enabled: true }];
```

Here is a fiddle of my progress thus far: https://jsfiddle.net/5L5q01yk/2/
So far its checking through for anything schedules that happen today and then finding out of the possibilities the closest hour to the current. I need it to be the next occurrence whether its today or not.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Also another flaw I have currently is my code will find the closest hour to now and its needs to be the next closest

Answer (score 1):

I'd tackle this by mapping your initial inputs to an array of dates that represent the next available dates in your schedule, then it is simple to reduce this to the minimum of the results. You could really do this in one step, but the intermediate data structure might be useful to you so I've left it.

```js
var collection = [{
    days: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    hour: 8,
    enabled: true
}, {
    days: [0, 1, 4, 5, 6],
    hour: 14,
    enabled: true
}, {
    days: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6],
    hour: 2,
    enabled: false
}, {
    days: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6],
    hour: 14,
    enabled: true
}];

var nextTime = null;
var now = new Date();
var dayOfMonth = now.getDate();
var month = now.getMonth();
var dayOfWeek = now.getDay();
var year = now.getFullYear();
var hour = now.getHours();

var nextPossibleTimes = collection.map(function(daySchedule) {
  daySchedule.days = daySchedule.days.map(function(scheduledDay) {
    var dayOffset = scheduledDay - dayOfWeek;
    if ((scheduledDay < dayOfWeek) || (scheduledDay === dayOfWeek && daySchedule.hour < hour)) {
      //add a week
      dayOffset += 7;
    }
    return new Date(year, month, dayOfMonth + dayOffset, daySchedule.hour);
  });
  return daySchedule;
});

nextPossibleTimes.forEach(function(current) {
  current.days.forEach(function(date) {
    if (nextTime === null || nextTime > date)
      nextTime = date;
  });
});

var dateArr = nextTime.toString().split(" ");
var dateName = dateArr[0] + " " + dateArr[4];
  
console.log("Next available time: " + dateName);
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This isnt what I need. I need it to be agnostic to the actual date and just reference the current day IE Tuesday and look through the data and find the next day and hour that is closest to the current one.

Comment: A good example of working code would return the next possible from today so at this moment, Tuesday at 15/3 hours the next from the sample data would be Wednesday at 2am

Comment: @ChrisJ I was filtering out  the items where `enabled == false` so that's why you weren't getting the 2AM time. I removed that filter and  I also formatted the date so it only shows the day name and the time. Let me know if there are any other issues.

Comment: I found a more elegant way to do this. Sorry I was looking at the wrong model initially, but as I said I didnt want to actually assign real times to the schedule dates as I want them to be separate from date or year. Thanks for your efforts